# In python what is the best way to create JSON with multiple keys

Tags: python, json, dictionary

For example, I am trying to create something that lists information with data such as:

```
Accoun1: User 1: Last Used date
Account1: User 2: " "
Account2: User 3: " "
```

So on and so forth. I would like to have this data read as json later on for others that will use it but not being familiar with the intricacies of dictionaries I was wondering if there is a good way to do this effectively? Thanks!

Comment: Nested dictionaries or a list of dictionaries are reasonable choices and both convert to and from JSON without issue or any special conversion.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution:

```
import json

data = {
    'Account1': {
        'User1': 'Last Used Date',
        'User2': ' '
    },
    'Account2': {
        'User3': ' '
    }
}

print(json.dumps(data))
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs, it may provide more flexibility in future code to do a list of dicts like this:

```
accounts = \
[
   {
     "account": "Account1",
     "user": "User 1",
     "last_used": datestring
   },
   {
     "account": "Account1",
     "user": "User 2",
     "last_used": datestring
   },
   {
     "account": "Account2",
     "user": "User 3",
     "last_used": datestring
   }
 ]
```